# primes of the form of $2^n+y^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

I wonder what the numbers(primes) of the form of $2^n + x^2$ (where n is even) are called? What are their properties? Any references to look at?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you please provide some motivation for considering this particular property; to me it is not self-explanantory this is interesting. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Voted to close as not a real question, in view of lack of motivation. 

Answer (score 5):

Primes of the form $2^n+k$ have been considered, see the [talk](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/covertalkunder.pdf) of Carl Pomerance. Among the square numbers  $k=y^2$ the case $k=1$ is the
most famous one, e.g., primes of the from $2^n+1$. Then necessarily $n$ is a power of $2$, so that these primes are just the Fermat primes $F_k=2^{2^k}+1$.
Another special case are the primes of the form $2^n+n^2$, see sequence A064539 at integer sequences.
Then necessarily $n\equiv 0 \mod 3$.